# How to get Blob Key of file to be downloaded from BlobStore in Java?

Tags: java, blobstore

I have uploaded a file,say a.txt to the Google BlobStore. Using a separate java program, I need to download / write to a.txt. How do I get the BlobKey of a.txt in this second java file so that I can download it using the Serve method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yo can get all information about blobstore using following code

```
Iterator<BlobInfo> iterator = null;
iterator = new BlobInfoFactory().queryBlobInfos();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    system.out.println(iterator.next().getBlobKey());//You can put condition here whats your file name
    system.out.println(iterator.next().getFilename());
}
```

using this code you will get bob key and than you have to used servlet to send this key and serve blob as following code

```
String key = request.getparameter("blobkey");
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(key);
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, response);
```